# How to read a user input in a text filed in ruby on rails and pass the value to a shell script command

Tags: ruby-on-rails, shell

I am very new to ruby on rails and I have a very simple question.
I am able to read the user input from a text field in ruby on rails

```
@user = params[:user]
```

I have to pass this value as an argument to a shell script
I tried a number of things, but nothing works

```
run_command "./file.sh #{@user}"
```

and

```
%x(./file.sh #{@user})
```

The script receives "{user="

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: what a kind command u want to run ?

Answer (score 1):

First, make sure you escape any parameters you pass to command line. You may be easily attacked via command line injection this way. Try this instead:

```
system "/path/to/file.sh #{@user.shellescape}"
```

You may also want to try `exec`, depending on how you want to track output. Please see http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Kernel.html for more details on both